# how to align enumerated text in two columns

Tags: lists, enumerate, two-column

In projective geometry there is a duality principle between points and planes, i.e. every true statement yields a dual statement obtained by interchanging the the words "point" and "plane".

I am looking for a simple way of writing the corresponding statements side by side in two columns without having to align them manually; now and then there occur self-dual statements, which should therefore span the width of the page (not be columnized). I also want to enumerate the statements (one item for each pair of statements).

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \usepackage{enumerate}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=P\arabic*]
            \item \label{itm: P1} There are two lines, which have no point and no plane in common
            \item \label{itm: P2} In every line lie at least three points and three planes.
            \item \label{itm: P3} Two distinct planes have one and only one line in common.
            \item \label{itm: P3'} Two distinct points have one and only one line in common.
            \item \label{itm: P4} Two lines have a point in common if and only if they have a plane in common.
       \end{enumerate}
       \end{document}
```

I want P3 and P3' to be placed side by side. I want to continue the list with interruptions for quite a bit, which is why I would prefer working with cross-references to doing it manually...

I would be grateful for suggestions!

Comment: Do you mean something like what the [tasks](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks_en.pdf) package provide?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have only one item for each double-statement, or what would be even better: the same item for both parts of a double-statement (e.g. a number) but an additional item to distinguish the two parts (e.g. "a)" on the left and "b)" on the right).

Comment: The `\task!`  command is used for an item that spans all columns. For the ‘better’ way, are you looking for a macro which swaps ‘point’ and ‘plane’?

Comment: I still have problems with referencing to a task... is that possible in tasks? I have added an example for what I am looking for.

Comment: Put P3 and P3' in a multicols environment

Comment: Please always post compilable code rather than fragments. You are using non-standard macros here. (Or, rather, standard macros with non-standard definitions.) You could use a table, I guess, but `tasks` is better if @Bernard says so.

Comment: @Flynn's suggestion does what I was looking for, thanks! (or are there any reasons why a table would be better?).

Comment: @cfr I have made the code compilable now... thanks for pointing it out to me!

Comment: @Larry: Your code isn't compilable -- there's no `\documentclass` statement